# Last digit of a huge number

Tags: haskell, modulo

I'm solving [Last digit of a huge number](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5518a860a73e708c0a000027) in Codewars.

I managed to find out a way to calculate `odd number ^ odd number` and `odd number ^ even number`. However I got stuck in `even ^ even/odd` as the relation between the number and its power's mod is not obvious.

Here's what I managed to get:

```hs
lastDigit :: [Integer] -> Integer
lastDigit = (`rem` 10) . go
  where
    go [] = 1
    go [x] = x
    go (x : y : r)
      | odd x && odd y = x ^ (go (y : r) `rem` (x + 1))
      | odd x && even y = x ^ (foldMod y (go r) (x + 1))
      | otherwise = -- any hint?

foldMod :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
foldMod _ 0 _ = 1
foldMod base 1 modulo = base `rem` modulo
foldMod base power modulo = (base * foldMod base (power -1) modulo) `rem` modulo
```

Can anyone give some hints on how to do about the even cases?

Comment: Hint: `(a * b) mod c = (a mod c) * (b mod c) mod c`

Comment: You can in fact calculate the last digit in *O(1)* (given you can perform modulo in *O(1)*, by analyzing how repeatedly multiplying eventually will generate a "cycle".

Comment: Can you say in words what function you intend `go` to compute? I've been staring at it for some time and have not yet convinced myself that the current equations are correct for any of the obvious interpretations.

Comment: @DanielWagner yes, I also found my approach problematic after rethinking and trying some other approaches T_T

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I do not believe this can be done in O(1). Consider `lastDigit (replicate n 0)` for odd vs. even `n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend rethinking your approach, and beginning with a more general function. Specifically, can you compute

```
powMod :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer
```

where `powMod base exponents` computes the exponential tower described in the problem mod `base`? Note that when you recurse, you will recurse with a different `base` -- because the cycle lengths of the various first exponents are not necessarily all divisors of `base`. For example, in base 10, any first exponent with a last digit of 7 cycles every four goes, not every ten; the last digit of the powers goes like this:

```
x               0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
7^x `mod` 10    1 7 9 3 1 7 9 3
```

You'll also want to watch out for situations where the first exponent is not itself in the eventual cycle that gets reached; for example, in base 4, we have:

```
x              0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
2^x `mod` 4    1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So you can't look at *just* `` x `mod` 1 `` and infer from it what `` 2^x `mod` 4 `` is, even though the cycle length is `1`. (There are other examples, like `` 2^x `mod` 12 ``, where the cycle is longer than 1 and still doesn't have the original `2` in it.)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to calculate the entire number to know the last digit, there are fast, and less fast approaches that can calculate the last digit without having to worry about all the other digits.

A simple approach that can calculate *a<sup>b</sup>* in *O(log b)* time is by making use of the following equivalence:

*(a×b) mod m = ((a mod m) × (b mod m)) mod m*.

This means we can each time calculate the last digit and work with that. It thus means that as long as we can represent all numbers up to 81, we can calculate the *a<sup>b</sup> mod m* `powMod m a b`:

```
powMod :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
powMod m = go
    where go _ 0 = 1
          go a b | even n = r
                 | otherwise = (x * r) `mod` m
              where r = go ((a*a) `mod` m) (div b 2) `mod` m
```

If we assume we can calculate modulo, divide by two, check if a value is even, etc. in constant time, this runs in *O(log b)*.

But we can even do this faster by looking for cycles. Imagine that we have to calculate a power of 7, then 7^0 is 1, 7^1 is 7, 7^2 mod 10 = 9, etc. We can make a table with multiplications:

```
× │  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
──┼─────────────────────
0 │  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 │    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2 │      4 6 8 0 2 4 8 6
3 │        9 2 5 8 1 4 7
4 │          6 0 4 8 2 6
5 │            5 0 5 0 5
6 │              6 2 8 4
7 │                9 6 3
8 |                  4 2
9 |                    1
```

If we thus look at the last digit for a power of 7, we see that for:

```
power  │     │  last digit
──────────────────────────
 0     │     │           1
 1     │ 7*1 │           7
 2     │ 7*7 │           9
 3     │ 7*9 │           3
 4     │ 7*3 │           1
```

This thus means that there is a cycle, indeed, after each multiplication with 7, we move to the next state, and thus obtain the following graph:

```
1  →  7  →  9  →  3
 ↖_______________/
```

This thus means that the cycle has a length of four. It thus means that if we have to calculate 7 to the power of for example 374, then we know that these are 93 cycles of length four that have thus no impact, and two extra moves, we thus know that the last digit of *7<sup>393</sup>* is 9, without having to compute this number. Since such cycles has a maximum length of 10, this can thus done in constant time do determine the last digit of the decimal number.

Comment: `7^0 = 1`. Not sure how big a problem this makes for your answer.

Comment: @dfeuer: the rest of the answer assumes that 7^0=1, it was a typo I think :s.

Comment: @dfeuer: but these are not powers, but multiplications. These are then used for the second table.

Comment: I think this does not engage with the interesting part of the kata. Specifically: even computing the exponent to pass to your `powMod` in the first place is expensive (and probably doesn't fit in an `Int`), and you do not address the issue of making that cheaper. (You need to compute the cycles for several moduli smaller than 10 for that, e.g., and you don't talk about that. I think you also need to implement an operation for efficiently checking whether an exponential tower is at least as big as a given number, to deal with the issue where some cycles do not start immediately.)

Comment: @DanielWagner: but you do not need to calculate the entire exponent, since you only need to find out the length of the "cycle". If we for example have to calculate 3^(4^5), then we know that 3 has a cycle of four. So we are only interested in the modulo of (4^5) (the "last digit in a number with radix four if you want). So then we calculate (4^5 mod 4). We thus not only reduce the computation of (3^...), but also of (4^5) itself.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Certainly. But you didn't discuss the fact that this change-of-radix was needed, and didn't mention the issue of slow-start cycles, both of which are quite interesting (nontrivial) points of the computation that needs to be implemented IMO.